# PRD report is returning duplicate records

Tags: sql

The report is returning duplicate records. How to solve this?

I tried using the `DISTINCT` function but it's causing an error so the report is wrong.

I wanted to add `idd` item column so it will give yes/no as value y/n
idd item is a custom column hence it is stored in system as 10

In the `idd` item, I need only one value according to value stored in the system.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         s.person_id_external as stud_id,
         s.lname,
         s.fname,
         s.mi,
         e.stud_id      AS cpnt_studID,
         e.cpnt_typ_id  AS cpnt_cpntTypID,
         e.cpnt_id      AS cpnt_cpntID,
         A.USER_VALUE   AS IDD_ITEM,
         B.COL_NUM      AS COLUMN,
         e.rev_num      AS cpnt_revNum,
         e.rev_dte      AS cpnt_revDte,
         e.compl_dte    AS cpnt_complDte,
         e.cmpl_stat_id AS cpnt_cmplStatID,
         cp.cpnt_classification,
         cp.cpnt_title           AS cpnt_cpntDesc,
         e.SCHD_ID               AS cpnt_schdID,
         e.grade                 AS cpnt_grade,
         cs.cmpl_stat_desc       AS cpnt_cmplStatDesc,
         NVL(e.total_hrs, 0.0)   AS cpnt_totalHRS,
         NVL(e.credit_hrs, 0.0)  AS cpnt_creditHRS,
         NVL(e.contact_hrs, 0.0) AS cpnt_contactHRS,
         NVL(e.cpe_hrs, 0.0)     AS cpnt_cpeHRS,
         NVL(oi.price, 0)        AS cpnt_tuition,
         e.inst_name             AS cpnt_instName,
         e.comments              AS cpnt_comment,
         e.es_user_name          AS cpnt_esUserName,
         e.lst_upd_tstmp         AS cpnt_lstUpdTstmp,
         e.esig_meaning_code_id
            || '  '
            || e.esig_meaning_code_desc AS cpnt_esigMeaningCode,
         e.currency_code             AS cpnt_currencyCode,
         cur.symbol                  AS cpnt_symbol,
         NULL                        AS ext_studID,
         NULL                        AS ext_cpntTypID,
         NULL                        AS ext_cpntID,
         NULL                        AS ext_revDte,
         NULL                        AS ext_complDte,
         NULL                        AS ext_cmplStatID,
    NULL                        AS ext_cpntDesc,
    NULL                        AS ext_grade,
    NULL                        AS ext_cmplStatDesc,
    NULL                        AS ext_totalHRS,
    NULL                        AS ext_creditHRS,
    NULL                        AS ext_contactHRS,
    NULL                        AS ext_cpeHRS,
    NULL                        AS ext_tuition,
    NULL                        AS ext_instName,
    NULL                        AS ext_comments ,
    NULL                        AS ext_esUserName,
    NULL                        AS ext_lstUpdTstmp,
    NULL                        AS ext_esigMeaningCode,
    NULL                        AS ext_currencyCode,
    NULL                        AS ext_symbol
FROM PA_CPNT_EVTHST e,
    pa_fin_order_item oi,
    pa_currency cur,
    pa_student s,
    PA_CMPL_STAT cs,
    pa_cpnt cp,
    pa_program p,
    Pa_cpnt_user A,
    PA_USRCL_CPNT B,
    pa_stud_program sp
WHERE e.stud_id             = s.stud_id (+)
AND e.cmpl_stat_id          = cs.cmpl_stat_id
AND e.currency_code         = cur.currency_code(+)
AND e.order_item_id         = oi.order_item_id(+)
AND cp.cpnt_typ_id(+)       = e.cpnt_typ_id
AND cp.cpnt_id(+)           = e.cpnt_id
AND cp.rev_dte(+)           = e.rev_dte
AND s.notactive             = 'N'
AND cp.cpnt_classification IN ('CONTINUOUS ONLINE ACCESS','BLENDED','PHYSICAL GOOD','TIME-BASED','EXTERNAL-COURSE','PROGRAM')
AND e.cpnt_typ_id           = sp.cpnt_typ_id(+)
AND e.cpnt_id               = sp.cpnt_id(+)
AND e.rev_dte               = sp.rev_dte(+)
AND e.stud_id               = sp.stud_id(+)
AND A.COL_NUM = B.COL_NUM
AND A.COL_NUM ='10'
AND e.compl_dte             = sp.compl_dte(+)
AND sp.program_sys_guid     = p.program_sys_guid(+)
/**  and e.compl_dte >= [FromDate] 
         AND not (pkg_Sql.sub_days(e.compl_dte ,1)) > [ToDate] */
/** and s.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
UNION
SELECT s.person_id_external ,
    s.lname,
    s.fname,
    s.mi,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_studID,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_cpntTypID,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_cpntID,
    A.USER_VALUE   AS IDD_ITEM,
    B.COL_NUM      AS COLUMN,
    
--(SELECT k.label FROM pa_usrcl_cpnt k WHERE e.LST_UPD_USR = k.LST_UPD_USR AND  k.label IS NOT NULL AND k.col_num ='10') AS IDD_ITEM,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_revNum,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_revDte,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_complDte,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_cmplStatID,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_classification,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_cpntDesc,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_grade,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_cmplStatDesc,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_schdID,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_totalHRS,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_creditHRS,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_contactHRS,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_cpeHRS,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_tuition,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_instName,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_comment,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_esUserName,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_lstUpdTstmp,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_esigMeaningCode,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_currencyCode,
    NULL                  AS cpnt_symbol,
    e.stud_id             AS ext_studID,
    NULL                  AS ext_cpntTypID,
    NULL                  AS ext_cpntID,
    NULL                  AS ext_revDte,
    e.compl_dte           AS ext_complDte,
    NULL                  AS ext_cmplStatID,
    e.cpnt_desc           AS ext_cpntDesc,
    e.grade               AS ext_grade,
    NULL                  AS ext_cmplStatDesc,
    NVL(e.total_hrs, 0)   AS ext_totalHRS,
    NVL(e.credit_hrs, 0)  AS ext_creditHRS,
    NVL(e.contact_hrs, 0) AS ext_contactHRS,
    NVL(e.cpe_hrs, 0)     AS ext_cpeHRS,
    NVL(e.price_paid, 0)  AS ext_tuition,
    e.inst_name           AS ext_instName,
    e.comments            AS ext_comments ,
    e.es_user_name        AS ext_esUserName,
    e.lst_upd_tstmp       AS ext_lstUpdTstmp,
    e.esig_meaning_code_id
    || '  '
    || e.esig_meaning_code_desc AS ext_esigMeaningCode,
    e.currency_code             AS ext_currencyCode,
    cur.symbol                  AS ext_symbol
FROM PA_XCPNT_EVTHST e,
    pa_currency cur,
    pa_student s,
    Pa_cpnt_user A,
    PA_USRCL_CPNT B
WHERE e.stud_id     = s.stud_id(+)
AND e.currency_code = cur.currency_code(+)
AND s.notactive     = 'N'
AND A.COL_NUM = B.COL_NUM
AND A.COL_NUM ='10'

    /** and e.compl_dte >= [FromDate] 
            AND not (pkg_Sql.sub_days(e.compl_dte ,1)) > [ToDate] */
    /** and s.stud_id in [UserSearch] */
    /** and s.stud_id in [UserSearch]
     and [security:pa_student s] */
ORDER BY lname ,
    fname ,
    cpnt_cpnttypid ,
    cpnt_cpntid ,
    cpnt_revdte )
```

Expecting idd item to give one value only

Comment: Try to add foreign key mapping in where claws with any of the other tables in the query with the any one of the table 'Pa_cpnt_user' or 'PA_USRCL_CPNT'.

Comment: I’d start by learning ANDI SQL join syntax as it will make your life much easier - also the syntax you are using has been outdated for 30+ years. Also, try creating a minimal reproducible example, as I’m guessing that most of the SQL you’ve provided is irrelevant to your actual issue

Comment: @NickW i used a standard report on which i made changes just for idd item. requirement is to add idd item coloumn and get values as Y/N .

Comment: @SudiptoBhattacharya okay  let me try that

Comment: @SudiptoBhattacharya could you please suggest how and where i can put that

Comment: In where clawse like a.<someid>=other than b. <someid> must be a foreign key. As I do not know your table structure. I could not help more on this.